# Can there exist such a harmonic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $D=\{z:Im(z)>0, |Re(z)|<\pi/2\}$ be a half strip. Let $L_1$ be the left boundary:\
$L_1=\{z:Re(z)=-\pi/2,Im(z)>0\}$. Similarly, let $L_2=\{z:Re(z)=\pi/2,Im(z)>0\}$, $L_3=\{z:|Re(z)|<\pi/2,Im(z)=0\}$. Can a harmonic function be found if $u|_{L_1}=1$, $u|_{L_2}=3$, $u|_{L_3}=5$?.

Comment: You should be clearer about the properties of $u.$ Is $u$ continuous on $D \cup L_1 \cup L_2\cup L_3?$ Also, what does this have to do with several complex variables?

Comment: @zhw when I am seeking for a harmonic function I presume the function to be at least twice continuously differentiable in $D$ in the regular sense and not in the weak sense in $D$. Of course, I need continuity on $L_1\bigcup L_2\bigcup L_3$.

Comment: Continuity on $L_1\cup L_2\cup L_3$ is obvious. It's continuity on $D\cup L_1\cup L_2\cup L_3$ that we need.

Comment: @zhw...Well, being twice differentiable in the interior and continuous on the boundary obviously implies continuity of the function in $D\bigcup L_1\bigcup L_2\bigcup L_3$. I don't see what is the relevance of your answer to this question. Could you please elaborate?.

Comment: No, that's not true. Being continuous on $L_1\cup L_2 \cup L_3$ does not imply continuity on $D\cup L_1\cup L_2 \cup L_3$ For example, the function that equals $0$ on $D$ and equals $1$  on $L_1\cup L_2 \cup L_3$ is continuous on $L_1\cup L_2 \cup L_3$  but not on $D\cup L_1\cup L_2 \cup L_3$

Comment: @zhw...That's ok...but the requirement of the question demands that the harmonic function is continuously extendable to the boundary and the boundary values coincides with boundary values prescribed in the question. Do you have any idea of proceeding or at least a way to see if such a harmonic function doesn't exist?.